# How to open a Pyqt 3.3 ui file with QtDesigner 4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I've a PyQt 4 installed (I can't find PyQt 3 for Windows) and I would like to open a QtDesigner ui file which has been created with QtDesigner 3.3.

When I open this file I've the following message:

`Please use uic3 -convert to convert to Qt4`

Unfortunately, I don't see the uic3 tool in the bin folder of my install.

Does anybody know how can I can convert this file to QtDesigner 4?

Additional quastion: Where to download PyQy3 binaries for Windows?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt3 and Qt4 aren't fully compatible so you may need to make some manual tweaks after uic3 converts.

That said, the uic3 tool was installed on my system when I installed the Qt SDK, in C:\Qt\2010.01\qt\bin

Qt SDK: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads

Comment: Ok. I guess that I've to install the whole SDK to get this tool which is not in pyqt

Answer (score 1):

Try finding `pyuic3` or rather `pyuic4`. Since you are using PyQt all your qt tools have py in front (like `pyrcc4` or `pyuicc4`).

I am not sure, that there are pyqt3 binaries for windows. Are you sure that Phil Thompson did PyQt3 also for windows at the time? If so, they would be on riverbank site, I guess, but I can't find them there. Tried compiling the source yourself?

Comment: No I didn't try and I would like to avoid compiling qt3 just for opening a ui file